# Google cloud CDN

Tags: dns, google-cloud-storage

I've got my production assets being server from a google cloud storage, acting as a CDN.

The url is something like this (not a real path) :

```
http://storage.googleapis.com/production-store/assets/main.css
```

`production-store` is a bucket, `assets` is a root folder.

Now I added a `CNAME` record on my domain like this `static.mydomain.com` to be alias for `storage.googleapis.com` but now when I do this :

```
http://static.mydomain.com/production-store/assets/main.css
```

The google gives me this error :

```
The requested URL /production-store/assets/main.css was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

I also host my domain DNS with google cloud, using google cloud DNS.
What am I missing here? Why is this not working?

Comment: This question is strictly about professional network administration, not SW development, and therefore suitable for ServerFault, **not** StackOverflow -- I recommend you move it there.  (Don't worry, we monitor, and try to help on!, both sites - my objection is strictly about not asking non-SW-dev Qs on Stackoverflow!).  FWIW I think you're stumbling into the typical "CNAME doesn't change HTTP's Host header" trap covered e.g at http://serverfault.com/questions/147853/cname-how-will-the-url-be-in-the-http-request ...

Comment: @AlexMartelli thanks for your response Alex I should have probably asked there. At this point I'm the SW developer, infrastructure, design, qa, business, support person :) thanks

Comment: I understand about the "wearing all hats" issue, believe me -- I was in startups once, midway through my career (not with much actual success, but hey!, I **did** learn a lot, and thereby personally grow...).  Nevertheless, *please* try to help us trying to help you, by targeting yr Qs appropriately -- making our supporter lives an epsilon easier WILL make your supportee's life easier by *at least* 1:1 -- trust me on this!-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli thanks for the follow up, you guys are doing great job with support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your CNAME to point to c.storage.googleapis.com instead of storage.googleapis.com

See Also:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris#cname
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration